# How to log runnable within RejectedExecutionHandler

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I wanna to log failed runnables.

For that I consider:

```
public class LoggableRejectedExecutorHanlder implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
@Override
public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
    ....
    log.error(" rejected task" + r);
}
...

service.submit(new Runnable() { ... public String toString() {return xxx;})
```

That class I'm going to use within ThreadPoolExecutor.RejectedExecutionHandler.

Unfortunately in log I see that r is a FutureTask, and my implementation of toString is not used. Within FutureTask I see that my runnable is wrapped inside private final sync property.

Is there a good way (besides reflection) for me to log within the rejectedHandler my runnable's toString?

Comment: The only thing that is coming to my mind, is to not use `RejectExecutionHandler` but to catch `RejectedExecutionException` while submitting the task - this would give u direct access to the task object that is beeing submited.

Comment: What? Did I write to log all of them? Just log rejected tasks... The one that throws `RejectedExecutionException`. Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: yep..., but there are nearly 100 places where they are submitted and some of the code is not easily changeable etc

Comment: Now thats a different problem. Are you using single executors pool or multiple thread pools? If single, than you could wrap the service and proxy submitions adding `try-catch` for rejections.